# Q: Distinction between levels() and unique() for zero-length strings in data frame

Tags: r

If a column in a data frame contains a zero-length string, passing it to the levels() function will return the zero-length string.  However, unique() will not.  This seems counter-intuitive to me, and I haven't been able to find any documentation that explains this.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Example:

```
d <- data.frame( col1 = c("", 'a', 'b'))  # Contains "".
```

Call unique():

```
unique(d$col1)
```

unique() does not return the zero-length string element:

```
[1]   a b
Levels:  a b
```

levels() includes "" in the results:

```
levels(d$col1)
[1] ""  "a" "b"
```

Comment: The output of `unique` does return "", but since the double quotes are missing in the print out, it is a bit more difficult to recognize. To see this, create a data.frame with only "a" and "b" and then compare the spacing in the output. Note also that col1 is not a character type, but rather is a factor. To get character vectors with `data.frame`, use stringsAsFactors=FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with printing methods. From the documentation, the return value for `unique`:

> For a vector, an object of the same type of x, but with only one copy of each duplicated element. No attributes are copied (so the result has no names).

And indeed, you can see that `unique` return a factor because `col1` is also a factor:

```
class(unique(d$col1))
[1] "factor"
```

Whereas, the return value for `levels` is a character vector:

```
class(levels(d$col1))
[1] "character"
```

And thus, `unique` does print the empty string but without the double quotes. An alternative would be to define the df without factor columns:

```
d <- data.frame(col1 = c("", 'a', 'b'), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And here `unique` will indeed return the wanted "". Of course `levels` only applies to factors and would no longer be adequate:

```
unique(d$col1)
[1] ""  "a" "b"
```